# arcpy Geometry.union(Geometry) ValueError

Tags: arcpy, line, python-2.7, union, valueerror

In this script, I want to extract **several polylines** from one polyline.

The data comes from this link : [Lignes aériennes RTE au 22 décembre 2017 INF 45 kV](https://opendata.rte-france.com/explore/dataset/lignes-aeriennes/download/?format=shp&disjunctive.etat=true&disjunctive.tension=true&refine.tension=INF%2045%20kV&timezone=Europe/Berlin)

In the flow, I merge the extracted polylines in order to form only one using the arcpy function **union** :

```py
import arcpy

count = 2  # initialisation de la distance
incertitude = 0.5  # incertitude autour de la distance
distance = count
polyline = r"C:\lignes-aeriennes.shp"
request = "code_ligne = 'SSVI5L12URCUR'"
feature = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(polyline, "feature_class")
polyline_selection = 
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("feature_class", "NEW_SELECTION", request)
mem_line = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\mem_line", "mem_line", "POLYLINE", "", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", polyline_selection)
print "mem_line --> " + str(mem_line)
arcpy.AddField_management(mem_line, "LineOID", "LONG")  # ajout du champ LineOID de type LONG
arcpy.AddField_management(mem_line, "Value", "FLOAT")  # ajout du champ Value de type FLOAT
result = arcpy.GetCount_management(polyline_selection)
print "result --> " + str(result)
features = int(result.getOutput(0))
print "features --> " + str(features)
search_fields = ["SHAPE@", "OID@"]  # polyline_selection
insert_fields = ["SHAPE@", "LineOID", "Value", "SHAPE@LENGTH"]  # mem_line
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyline_selection, (search_fields)) as search:  # polyline_selection
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(mem_line, (insert_fields)) as insert:  # mem_line
        for row in search:  # pour chaque ligne
            line_geom = row[0]  # geometrie
            print "line_geom --> " + str(line_geom)
            length = float(line_geom.getLength('PRESERVE_SHAPE', 'METERS'))  # longueur
            print "length --> " + str(length)
            oid = str(row[1])  # ID
            print "oid --> " + str(oid)
            start = arcpy.PointGeometry(line_geom.firstPoint)  # debut
            print "start --> " + str(start)
            end = arcpy.PointGeometry(line_geom.lastPoint)  # fin
            print "end --> " + str(end)
            segment = line_geom.segmentAlongLine(count - incertitude, count + incertitude, False)  # extraction
            print "TYPE segment --> " + str(type(segment))
            segment_length = segment.getLength('PRESERVE_SHAPE', 'METERS')  # longueur
            print "new length --> " + str(segment_length)
            count += distance  # point suivant
            while count <= length:  # tant qu il reste de la longueur
                ligne = line_geom.segmentAlongLine(count - incertitude, count + incertitude, False)  # extraction
                ligne_length = ligne.getLength('PRESERVE_SHAPE', 'METERS')  # longueur
                print "ligne_length --> " + str(ligne_length)
                print "TYPE segment --> " + str(type(ligne))
                segment.union(ligne)  # ValueError possible !!!
                count += distance  # point suivant
            segment_length = segment.getLength('PRESERVE_SHAPE', 'METERS')  # longueur totale
            print "new length --> " + str(segment_length)
            insert.insertRow((segment, oid, count, segment_length))  # insertion
del polyline
del request
del feature
del polyline_selection
del mem_line
```

However, when the merge happens, a **ValueError** appears :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-7582fbec95bb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/exemple.py", line 44, in <module>
    segment.union(ligne)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 855, in union
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.Union(*gp_fixargs((other,))))

ValueError: <geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x09D657C0>
```

I don't understand this **ValueError**. This Polyline have the same type and are not corrupted, I can display them correctly in **ArcMap**.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using a polyline created with the **segmentAlongLine** method.

I solved it like this:

```
fixed_segment = arcpy.Polyline(segment.getPart(0), segment.spatialReference)
```

Assuming that there is only one part in the polyline.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code and it did not yield a ValueError.

```py
>>> import arcpy
>>> p1 = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0,0), arcpy.Point(5,5)]))
>>> p2 = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(2,2), arcpy.Point(4,4)]))
>>> p1.union(p2)
<Polyline object at 0x302bb50[0x302bea0]>
>>> p2 = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(20,20), arcpy.Point(40,40)]))
>>> p1.union(p2)
<Polyline object at 0x302b9f0[0x3885cc0]>
>>> p1.length
7.0710678118654755
>>> p2.length
28.284271247461902
```

So I tried it when the lines intersect and not at all. So I was wondering if your data (which you don't actually explain anything about) is incompatible or corrupt?

For example how have you constructed the geometries? May be you created corrupted geometries or are you retrieving them from a data source? Are they the same coordinate system?

Based upon my simple example, my money is on the source of your data which you have not adequately described for others to help.

Comment: You're certainly right... I retrieve the data by the function **arcpy.da.SearchCursor**. Even if I succes to display them in ArcMap, the use of the function **arcpy.Describe(Polyline).spatialReference** send the same ValueError. There is a problem with data :'(

Comment: @Rudymil1 so what is your data source?

Comment: In fact I extract polylines from a GDB (**arcpy.da.SearchCursor**). Then, for each polyline, I extract some pieces (**polyligne.segmentAlongLine**) that I merge then (**polyligne.union (polyline)**). And that's where it goes wrong.

Comment: And to answer your question, I retrieve the data on this link : [Lignes aériennes RTE au 22 décembre 2017 INF 45 kV](https://opendata.rte-france.com/explore/dataset/lignes-aeriennes/download/?format=shp&disjunctive.etat=true&disjunctive.tension=true&refine.tension=INF+45+kV&timezone=Europe/Berlin)

Comment: @Rudymil1 can you add to your original question the code that extracts the geometries , creates a segment then unions them. What are you union them with? Looking at your sample data none of the lines overlap. So if you are attempting to union the lines with themselves I would expect Null geometries returned but that would not explain the ValueError message.